# I keep getting a syntax error when trying to install Bumblebee

Tags: graphics, vaio, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm getting a syntax error when trying to install Bumblebee (Hardware graphics switcher). I'm running Ubuntu 11.04. My computer is a Sony Vaio Z (VPCZ122Gx). The github page is here: https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee

Bumblebee (previously called prime-ng) is the linux alternative to the Nvidia Optimus features in Windows

The syntax error is:

```
./install.sh: line 532: syntax error near unexpected token `['
./install.sh: line 532: ` if [ -f /usr/local/bin/bumblebee-enablecard ]'
```

Thanks in advance!
--
Andrew Hauser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in the installer for the version of Bumblebee that you downloaded. It was [fixed only a couple hours ago](https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee/commit/6dcb99d7c130565cbfe9c1ef98196bc1de377400#install.sh); update your Git repository and try installing Bumblebee again.